# Group 4 tables into one, with each table as one column?

Tags: matlab, grouping, matlab-table

I have 4 tables (`A`,`B`,`C`,`D`) in Matlab with 102 columns (e.g. `X`, `Y`, `W`, `Z`), all containing 52000 rows (e.g. `0,1,2,...`).

I want to merge them into one big table containing all of the data.

This is the output I want:

```matlab
T   Column_names   A    B    C     D  

0       X          a(0)  b(0)  c(0)  d(0)
0       Y          a(0)  b(0)  c(0)  d(0)
0       W          a(0)  b(0)  c(0)  d(0)
0       Z          a(0)  b(0)  c(0)  d(0)
1       X          a(1)  b(1)  c(1)  d(1)
1       y          a(1)  b(1)  c(1)  d(1)
1       w          a(1)  b(1)  c(1)  d(1)
1       z          a(1)  b(1)  c(1)  d(1)
2    ...
...
```

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created an example of 3 tables (`A,B,C`), each with 3 columns (`X,Y,Z`) and 4 rows.

Then the following steps achieve what you want...

1. It's trivial to add the row index `T`.
2. You can then use `stack` to create a tall table with the columns stacked (and labelled as a new column)
3. Finally an `outerjoin` will merge all of the tables together. You could just concatenate them, but this has two disadvantages

   - You would have to deal with duplicate column names
   - You would have to *assume* that the rows are in the same order.

The code is as follows, please see the comments for details.

```
% Dummy data
X = (1:12).';
Y = rand(12,1);
Z = primes(40).';
% Create tables with 4 rows each
A = table( X(1:4), Y(1:4), Z(1:4), 'VariableNames', {'X','Y','Z'} );
B = table( X(5:8), Y(5:8), Z(5:8), 'VariableNames', {'X','Y','Z'} );
C = table( X(9:12), Y(9:12), Z(9:12), 'VariableNames', {'X','Y','Z'} );

% Add the row index T
A.T = (1:size(A,1)).';
B.T = (1:size(B,1)).';
C.T = (1:size(C,1)).';

% Joining
% First, stack the tables to get column names as a column
As = stack( A, {'X','Y','Z'}, 'IndexVariableName', 'Column_names', 'NewDataVariableName', 'A' );
Bs = stack( B, {'X','Y','Z'}, 'IndexVariableName', 'Column_names', 'NewDataVariableName', 'B' );
Cs = stack( C, {'X','Y','Z'}, 'IndexVariableName', 'Column_names', 'NewDataVariableName', 'C' );

% Now just concatenate the tables.
% We can do this robustly with a 'join'.
tbls = {As,Bs,Cs};
% Loop over the tables for greatest flexibility
output = tbls{1};
for ii = 2:numel(tbls)
    output = outerjoin( output, tbls{ii}, 'Keys', {'T','Column_names'}, 'MergeKeys', true );
end
```

---

Output:

[image: output]